# screen width vs visible portion

Tags: javascript, screen

I have a little problem with JavaScript, to get the screen width we use screen.width which returns the overall screen resolution, is there a command to get the resolution of the visible portion of the browser, like when the browser is not maximized?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
function width(){
   return window.innerWidth 
       || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
       || document.body.clientWidth 
       || 0;
}

function height(){
   return window.innerHeight 
       || document.documentElement.clientHeight 
       || document.body.clientHeight 
       || 0;
}
```

Use them to return the `height()` or `width()` of the visible window.

[JSFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/jcoc611/EkXwD/2/)

Comment: Thank you sir, window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight is what I want, it just works! but why all the other code?

Comment: @JCOC No need to write the window.innerWidth twice by using the ternary operator. Just use ||: `return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth || 0;`

Comment: In the original code I checked if `window.innerWidth` was a number, but I was too lazy to convert it from my framework to plain JS.

Comment: Cleaner I guess, but it does exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The area you're describing is the viewport, and can typically be accessed by using **window.innerWidth** or **window.innerHeight** in modern browsers. IE6 is a bit different, but more information on handling the viewport width for all browsers can be found in [this tutorial on obtaining viewport size](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/get-viewport-size-javascript/).

Answer (score 1):

I saw that the question was answered, but here is the code I used with an image to ilustrate.

```
function height(){
return(window.innerHeight)?
window.innerHeight:
document.documentElement.clientHeight||document.body.clientHeight||0;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.first, .second').css('height',height());
});
$(window).resize(function() {
$('.first, .second').css('height',height());
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/madaaah/LD4gN/1/)