# How to make the width of this popup a percentage of the user's screen size?

Tags: javascript, popup

The following code is from JotForm (a contact form generating tool), and when the user clicks a particular link, a popup window appears with a form inside it.

Below is the Javascript powering the popup. I am trying to make it user-friendly on iPhones, and so I am trying to change the width of the popup to a relative size (eg: percentage instead of pixels), however when I set the width as 50%, the button the user clicked to open the form no longer works.

```
<script src="http://cdn.jotfor.ms/min/g=feedback2" type="text/javascript">
new JotformFeedback({
formId:'30623215881349',
base:'http://jotformeu.com/',
windowTitle:'Request A Free Callback',
background:'#FFA500',
fontColor:'#FFFFFF',
type:false,
height:351,
width:600
});
</script>
```

Any help with adjusting this code so as to make the popup a percentage (50, for example) of the width of the users screen, is very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: `width: window.screen.width / 2`? It's not a standard, however.

Comment: @apsillers shouldn't it be `window.screen.availWidth`?

Comment: @LukeW. Yes, it should be! Also, I think I have misunderstood the OP's question.

Comment: Dan, are you creating an actual popup window, or just a modal display overlaying the page? From the language in your question, I initially thought you were making a popup, but your mention of iOS suggests to me that you're making a modal, since my understanding is that iOS can't show popups, except as new pages (so setting a width would be meaningless).

Comment: @aspillers Thanks very much for the response, apologies for taking so long to get back.
It is indeed a modal window, sorry for the confusion. 
To see the window in action, you can go to http://www.pinknoise-systems.co.uk/, and click "request a callback" (under the sliding carousel).

Answer (score 3):

Can't you do something like this:

```
var w = window.innerWidth||document.documentElement.clientWidth||document.body.clientWidth;
```

Then set the width property to : `w`?

Refer to [screen width vs visible portion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987309/screen-width-vs-visible-portion)