# place the tooltip on available large space inside a container in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I have an editor in which the user can create a banner the user can drag the element in any position he/she wants inside a banner, the element has a tooltip, on hover, it should show the tooltip positioned on the side where the space is larger than the rest (top, left, bottom, right) and the tooltip should never go outside the container no matter what.

HTML

```
<div id="banner-container" class="banner-container">
    <span
        (cdkDragReleased)="onCircleButtonDragEnd($event)"
        id="point-button"
        class="point-button"
        cdkDragBoundary=".banner-container"
        cdkDrag
        [style.left]="banner.bannerElements.x"
        [style.top]="banner.bannerElements.y"
        [attr.data-id]="banner.bannerElements.buttonId"
        [id]="'button-' + banner.bannerElements.buttonId"
    ></span>
    <span
        id="tooltip"
        [style.left]="banner.bannerElements.x"
        [style.top]="banner.bannerElements.y"
        [attr.data-id]="banner.bannerElements.tooltipId"
        [id]="'button-' + banner.bannerElements.tooltipId"
    >
        Szanujemy Twoją prywatność
    </span>
</div>
```

TS

```
  banner = {
        buttonId: 11,
        tooltipId: 2,
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };

onCircleButtonDragEnd(event) {
        const container = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;
        const containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
        const containerHeight = container.clientHeight;

        this.banner.y =
            ((event.clientX - container.getBoundingClientRect().left) /
                containerWidth) *
            100;
        this.banner.y =
            ((event.clientY - container.getBoundingClientRect().top) /
                containerHeight) *
            100;
    }``
```

CSS

```
.point-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(179, 115, 188);
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.point-button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    0 8px 10px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 14px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.banner-container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: dotted #ccc 2px;
}
.tooltip {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px #ccc solid;
  display: none;
}
.point-button:hover + .tooltip {
  display: block;
}`
```

**

> LIVE DEMO

** : [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/havyf3?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.css)

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**

> Update:

**
Without using any library

Comment: So, you still working on this drag&drop madness... have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51066294/1657465)?

Comment: @luiscla27 I checked but that is not the same as I want here , but thanks for the link

Comment: you can use some tooltip librarys.
https://userguiding.com/blog/angular-tooltip/
 i tried it but its shows some version errors.

Comment: @sawacrow Thanks but without using any library , I can't use  any external links

Comment: @luiscla27 Yes, a user can create a different banner image with different sizes, the user can add many points(buttons as he/she wishes), he/she can position the button at any position on the banner by dragging and dropping the point, I save the points individually with its details to the database, the point by default has tooltip when user add a point. so when you add the point the positions of the point and the tooltip are the same now we need to adjust the tooltip position accordingly to make sure, the tooltip appears on the side with larger space and should not go over the container

Comment: @luiscla27 if you check the BizzyBob solution that is what I want almost 99% just a minor fix and we are good to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### TLDR; [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77788241?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.css,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.html,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.ts).

---

You can create a function that does the math and logic of determining the `top` and `left` properties of the tooltip position. Then you can easily apply them using `[ngStyle]`:

```html
<div #container class="banner-container">
  <span #element class="point-button" cdkDrag
    [cdkDragBoundary]="container"
    (cdkDragReleased)="updateTooltipStyle()"
  ></span>
  <span #tooltip class="tooltip" [ngStyle]="tooltipStyle">
    This is a tooltip :-)
  </span>
</div>
```

```js
export class CdkDragDropHorizontalSortingExample implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('container') container!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('element') element!: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('tooltip') tooltip!: ElementRef;
 
  tooltipStyle = {};

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.updateTooltipStyle();
  }
  
  updateTooltipStyle() {
    const parent  = this.container.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const element = this.element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const tooltip = this.tooltip.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  
    const spaceLeft   = element.left  - parent.left;
    const spaceRight  = parent.right  - element.right;
    const spaceTop    = element.top   - parent.top;
    const spaceBottom = parent.bottom - element.bottom;

    const spaceX = Math.max(spaceLeft, spaceRight) - tooltip.width;
    const spaceY = Math.max(spaceTop, spaceBottom) - tooltip.height;

    let tooltipTop, tooltipLeft;

    if (spaceX > spaceY) {
      tooltipLeft = spaceLeft > spaceRight
        ? element.left - parent.left - tooltip.width - MARGIN
        : element.right - parent.left + MARGIN;

      tooltipTop = Math.min(Math.max(0, (element.top - parent.top) + (element.height - tooltip.height) / 2), parent.height - tooltip.height);

    } else {
      tooltipTop = spaceTop > spaceBottom
        ? element.top - parent.top - tooltip.height - MARGIN
        : element.bottom - parent.top + MARGIN;

      tooltipLeft = Math.min(Math.max(0, (element.left - parent.left) + (element.width - tooltip.width) / 2), parent.width - tooltip.width);
    }

    this.tooltipStyle = {
      left  : `${tooltipLeft}px`,
      top   : `${tooltipTop}px`,
      width : `${tooltip.width}px`
    };
  }

}
```

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77788241?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.css,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.html,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.ts) demo.

Comment: Hi bro, I currently testing your solution before accepting it, I have a minor bug so far, when I drag the point a little outside the middle to the right side the tooltip is on the left side and it goes out the container, the tooltip should never go out the container no matter what check the images below https://ibb.co/30RRcdp
https://ibb.co/b27SXFM
https://ibb.co/FmF7BS6

Comment: Looks like I wasn't taking the tooltip height/width into account when calculating available space.  I've updated the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-77788241?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.css,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.html,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.component.ts)

Comment: I have one more question, how do I get the button and tooltip assuming I have multiple buttons with tooltips, meaning how to get the current dragged elements assuming we have multiple elements?  note  tooltips are added only after the button is successfully created, meaning I am calling the function updateTooltipStyle() on success, check the image below https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vvYI.png, and my structure uses data-id to connect between the button and tooltip check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hwUO.png

Comment: I'm not clear at what point in your code do you need the reference. Do you need the reference so you can set the `id` and `data-id` properties of the element?  How are you generating your elements?  If they are embedded in a template using something like *ngFor, it should be simple to just bind to those properties to some variable.

Answer (score 2):

##### TLDR; [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/havyf3-h1funi?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.html,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.css)

---

Looking at the given demo there is a lot of things to cover:

1. the `$event` passed to the `onCircleButtonDragEnd` is not the `MouseEvent` object; the mouse event can be accessed via `$event.event` so when you try to assign the `event.currentTarget` to the `container` constant, it returns an error,
2. you don't really need to set `[style.left]` and `[style.top]` of the `point-button` because the `CdkDrag` directive already sets the proper position using the `transform: translate3d`,
3. you forgot to add the units to the `[style.left]` and `[style.top]` of the `tooltip` component so even if the values are calculated properly, the styles will not be bound to the element,
4. if you want the `tooltip` to float next to the draggable `point-button` it'd be best to set `position: relative` for the `banner-container` and `position: absolute` for the `tooltip`, otherwise they may both be misaligned (as one element influences the position of another),
5. in order to achieve what you want we need 3 things:

   I. the size of the `banner-container` in order to compute the position of the tooltip,

   II. the size of the `tooltip` as it influences the desired position,

   III. the size of the `point-button`.

We can start solving this by:

1. getting the mentioned sizes. The most straightforward way to achieve this in Angular is to use the `@ViewChild` decorator to get the `ElementRef` references and then get the desired dimensions.
2. adding the `AfterViewInit` hook in the component in which:

   I. you save the `tooltip` dimensions to use in the future,

   II. you set the initial `tooltip` position - the `point-button` position is fixed so this should be quite easy (I did it with the `setTimeout` delayed by `0` so Angular didn't complain about the value change during the lifecycles check),

   III. you hide the tooltip and set it's `position` to `absolute`. Setting the `position: absolute` or `display: none` in CSS may result in the wrong dimensions calculation, that's why I'd recommend to first display it the normal way and then hide. For the purpose of hiding the element in Angular you can just set its `hidden` attribute.

The next steps are just pure maths. As you presented in the pictures the position of the `tooltip` should be dependent on the `point-button` position. If you analyze it carefully you will notice that one of the possible ways to do this is to divide the rectangle container into 4 triangles using its diagonals and then set the `tooltip` position accordingly:

[image: the container division]

That's why we can tackle this problem by writing the function `computeTheSegment` that takes the position `(x, y)` of the point within the container of size `(width, height)` and then determines to which segment (`T`, `R`, `B` or `L`) the point belongs. It can be done by writing the diagonals equations explicitly (these are just the linear equations of the form `y = ax + b`) or by computing the projection coordinates for both the diagonals `d1` and `d2` and then comparing them to the original `x` and `y`.

Once we are done we just need to update the `tooltip` position in the `onCircleButtonDragEnd` method. We can do this the following way:

1. extract the `circle-button` position using the mentioned `ElementRef`, `window.getComputedStyle` and the `WebKitCSSMatrix` (to get the `x` and `y` translation from the `transform: translate3d` property)
2. add half of the `circle-button` width to the extracted position to determine the central point of the button,
3. compute the segment by providing the computed position and the `banner-container` sizes to the `computeTheSegment` method,
4. finally, setting the `x` and `y` of the tooltip depending on the segment the `circle-button` belongs to:

   - for the top and bottom position set the `x` of the tooltip to be the `circle-button` position minus half of the tooltip's width (and accordingly as it comes to the left and right positions and the `y` coordinate),
   - for the top and bottom position set the `y` of the tooltip to be next to the `circle-button` (and accordingly as it comes to the vertical segments),
   - remember that we don't want the `tooltip` to overflow from the container, so it's good to use the `Math.max(0, x)` function during the computation - if the value is negative it will be replaced by `0`.

I share the demo with you:
[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/havyf3-h1funi?file=src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.ts,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.html,src%2Fexample%2Fcdk-drag-drop.css)

Of course, it can be done in a more elegant way (e.g. with paying attention to the screen `resize` event which can influence the `banner-container` size). Nonetheless, I think it's the fine approach to solve this problem.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank you for your effort in trying to solve this, but you in the right path,  that solution does not give a working solution , check one of problems below https://ibb.co/rMWjJsc

Comment: Thank you, honestly I couldn't reproduce the issue from the screen