# How can I detect iPhone X screen width in landscape mode?

Tags: javascript, iphone, screen-size, iphone-x

I've added the following javascript to my site:

```
alert('screen width=' + screen.width);
```

When I open the site on my iPhone X it outputs 'screen width=375' in both portrait and landscape mode.

I would expect it to be 812px in landscape.

I've also tried this on my iPhone XR and it has the same behaviour.

Can anyone suggest why this might be?

Comment: what does `window.innerWidth` display?

Comment: @Ifaruki That's showing the right thing. Thanks. What's the difference?

Comment: check it out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443482/what-is-the-difference-between-window-innerwidth-and-screen-width

Comment: Thanks. So it's the width of the viewport rather than the screen. Still not sure why screen.width would be wrong though.

Comment: well if you have your phone infront of you you have a fixed width of your screen, if you rotate it, its still the same width... just rotatet!

Comment: Ah ok. Makes perfect sense now. Thanks