# why window.innerWidth is greater than window.screen.width

Tags: javascript, html, responsive-design, viewport

Under my angular app , i ve this meta , in the head of my index file

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
```

When using a 19 desktop screen (1280x1024) , strangely i get those values when using **Firefox**

```
window.screen.width : 1280
window.innerWidth : 1282
```

and with **Edge Chromium**

```
window.screen.width : 1280
window.innerWidth : 1067
```

the fierefox dimensions ,seems to be strange (the widow is fullscreen)

Someone can explain ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between window.innerWidth and screen.width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443482/what-is-the-difference-between-window-innerwidth-and-screen-width)

Comment: Is it possible that your browsers has different size? Maybe FF is not in full screen, but actually 2px out of screen?