# Jquery window.resize(event) => {} works for inspect element but not when the chrome (or edge) window is resized

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, window-resize

There are many many questions regarding resize (event) not working online, but I was only able to find [one](https://litmus.com/community/discussions/8311-chrome-no-longer-showing-responsive-layout-when-resizing-browser-window-with-local-html-file) that actually reflected my exact problem but did not have an answer.

When I use inspector, my website changes from the desktop version to the mobile version when it reaches the breakpoint of <= 540px width. However, when I resize the entire chrome window, nothing happens (even though my window does get smaller than 540px width).

I'm not sure if the mobile version will actually work on a mobile as I have no way of testing that currently, but I'm unsure as to whether this is a normal thing with Chrome and the website will work perfectly well on desktop and mobile or whether I'm doing something wrong.

The related piece of code:

```
$(window).resize((event) => {

      const windowWidth = window.screen.width;
      if (windowWidth <= 540) {

        $('.className1').addClass('d-none');
        $('.classname2').css("width", "100%");
        $('.classname3').css("left", "3%");
        $('.classname3').css("width", "100%");
        $('.classname4').css("width", "90%");
```

This is not the entire method but it basically shows the idea that css and attributes change based on window width dropping below 540px.

What I tried:

- Document.resize (failed)

I really hope this isn't a duplicate, it's hard to navigate the vast number of questions out there.

Comment: Your link mentions "local html file" - is that also the case for you?  Have you tried running it from a server?  `http://` vs `file://`

Comment: I actually missed that in the link, but I run it from htttp not from file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the `resize` event or with browser. It's occurring because you're using `window.screen.width`, which is relative to the **screen**, not to the browser window. It doesn't matter if you resize the browser window, the screen width will not change. For example, if your screen has resolution of 1900x1200, `screen.width` will always be 1900. Hence, you should use `window.innerWidth`, or just `innerWidth` to get the **viewport** width. To know more, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443482/what-is-the-difference-between-window-innerwidth-and-screen-width).

Your code would be that way:

```
(window).resize((event) => {

  if (innerWidth <= 540) {

    $('.className1').addClass('d-none');
    $('.classname2').css("width", "100%");
    $('.classname3').css("left", "3%");
    $('.classname3').css("width", "100%");
    $('.classname4').css("width", "90%");
```

An example of working code (open the snippet in full page and resize it):

```js
  $(window).resize((event) => {
      if (innerWidth <= 540) {
          document.write('It\'s working.');
      }
  });
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```