# Why is window.innerWidth smaller than screen.width even in full screen?

Tags: javascript, css, fullscreen, screen-resolution, browser-width

When my browser window is in full screen mode, the inner width of the window still seems to be smaller than my screen width. I am confused because (based on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37443482/what-is-the-difference-between-window-innerwidth-and-screen-width)) I thought that, if my inner window took up my entire screen, then it would have the same dimensions as my screen.

Instead, I receive the following values when I run window.innerWidth and screen.width in full screen mode:

**Screen width:** 1280 px

**Inner window width:** 625 px

My browser is zoomed to 100%.

Why doesn't the inner window width match the screen width when I put my browser in full screen mode?

Comment: What browser + OS are you seeing this? Which "fullscreen" mode are you using? The OS one, by either pressing a keyboard shortcut or clicking an icon in the browser's UI, or the one from `Element.requestFullScreen()`?

Comment: @Kaiido I am using Chrome 103 on Windows 10, and getting to full screen mode using element.requestFullScreen()

Comment: Check display settings. It could be possible that your scale is set to over 100% in Windows opposed to your browser.

Comment: @Caeden Thank you, that was the problem! If you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the right answer. Otherwise, I will post the answer myself and credit you.

Comment: Glad to see it was the problem! Thank you for offering to give credit -- typically this doesn't happen. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` return the dimensions of the viewport window instead of the display monitor, zooming into a webpage will decrease the values of both `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

Zooming in can happen both in the operating system and in the browser. If the viewport window covers the entire screen and `window.innerWidth` and `screen.width` do not match, it's most likely the OS that is zoomed in.

To fix this, just set the OS's zoom to 100%. This can be done in Windows by going to display settings and setting scale to 100%.